# Ordering issue with fprintf ---MATLAB

Tags: matlab, matrix, printf

I have got an *order* issue in my output while using the command

```
fprintf()
```

and look for advice to understand the cause of this matter, to the extent that matrix **A** is set up correctly:

**1/**

Code:

```
A=[normVaR_1d WHS_VaR1d STABLE_VaR1d;normES_1d WHS_ES1d STABLE_ES1d];
fprintf('norm\t  whs\t  stbl\n');
fprintf('%12.8f %12.8f %12.8f\n',A);

output =[0.0203 0.0233 0.0242 ; 0.0340 0.0301 0.0702]
```

wheras

```
expected_output=[0.0203 0.0242 0.0301 ; 0.0233 0.0340 0.0702]
```

**2/** to increase readability on my screen is there a way of adding a descriptive empty column with 2 strings 'va' && 'es' such as:

```
     norm     whs   stbl

va   0.0203  0.0242 0.0301

es   0.0233  0.0340 0.0702
```

Thanks

Comment: Hi! I've made a MATLAB chat room for us in case you wanted to discuss anything related to MATLAB that is off-topic, or if you want to discuss things that span longer than a comments block.  Stop by when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To fix your first issue:

you just have to change `A` with `A.'` that is print the transpose of A.

To fix your second issue there are (at least) two ways:

1) to define the names of the rows and to use a `for` loop to print each row of the matrix A

2) to use `table` (avaialble from R2013b)

This is the code for the above proposed solutions:

```
% Define an example matrix
A=[1 2 3;4 5 6]
% Define row names
r_names={'va';'es'};
% Define variables names
var_names={'norm' 'whs' 'stbl'};
disp('Question 1')
% Just print the matrix A
fprintf('%f %f %f\n',A.')

disp(' ')
disp('Question 2')
% Print matrix A with row names
fprintf('\tnorm\t whs\t stbl\n')
for i=1:2
   fprintf('%s %f %f %f\n',char(r_names(i)),A(i,:))
end   

disp(' ')

disp('Question 2 alternative')
% Print matrix A using "table"
norm=A(:,1);
whs=A(:,2);
stbl=A(:,3);

table(norm,whs,stbl,'rownames',r_names)
```

This is the output:

```
A =

     1     2     3
     4     5     6

Question 1
1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
4.000000 5.000000 6.000000

Question 2
    norm     whs     stbl
va 1.000000 2.000000 3.000000
es 4.000000 5.000000 6.000000

Question 2 alternative

ans = 

          norm    whs    stbl
          ____    ___    ____

    va    1       2      3   
    es    4       5      6
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I managed to get explanations in `1/` matching yours. Regarding `2/` I do appreciate the alternative solutions you provided.cheers.

Comment: Hi! I've made a MATLAB chat room for us in case you wanted to discuss anything related to MATLAB that is off-topic, or if you want to discuss things that span longer than a comments block.  Stop by when you have time! http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81987/matlab